# What prejudices could neighbors have when they see a Rammstein flag on the house?

Tags: rock

I've been listening to Rammstein since I was a teenager, and I've listened to all their songs an infinite number of times. Also the new band "Lindemann", inspires me.

What prejudices could neighbors have if they see a Rammstein flag on the house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a quick look at the [*Controversies* section of Wikipedia's article on the band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rammstein#Controversies) suggests that neighbors might have *any* prejudice on seeing that flag.  The band courts controversy actively, and their taste for using sarcasm and satire has caused many people to misconstrue the band's message.

Someone unfamiliar with the band, therefore, is more likely to think that the flag represents right-wing nationalistic views.  Someone familiar with the band is more likely to see it as an endorsement of left-leaning anti-establishment views.  Furthermore, those familiar with the band because of one of the many controversies they have sparked might associate the flag with that controversy.

Whether any person harboring any of these prejudices views you more or less favorably as a result will, of course, depend on what that person thinks of nationalism, the establishment, or the particular controversy.